# iPhone supports background running of applications?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an application in iPhone which will send ordinary sms to users at pre stated date and time. so I want to know is it possible in iPhone that the sms is sent to receivers automatically when time comes. also if you know some suggestions then please give me more suggestions so I can make it run successfully

Thanks

Comment: Not possible in any way.

Comment: You are not able to sending sms automatically via GSM carrier

Comment: so is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You must must must  click on send button to send SMS in iphone :)

Comment: @Rushabh so can I set popup box for it?

Comment: you can it with jailbroken phones

Comment: iPhone doesn't provide any services like timer for background process?

Comment: @SumitBijvani u need to use webservice for this.

Comment: @HinataHyuga thanks for giving me basic idea. so is this possible with webservice to send automatic SMS in future?

Comment: @SumitBijvani Yes. I already have an app like this on appstore.what pravi jay suggested, will be ur correct approach for this.

Comment: @HinataHyuga can you please show me you app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one thing. You can make web service in .net or in php. Or there are third party api for sending sms to other users like way2sms.com. these are just for .net and in php.

Answer (score 0):

with jailbroken phones this is feasible.. I don't know the detail though..

anyway, with stock iphone it isnt possible